# not found error when executing bash script on Mac OS

Tags: macos, bash

I'm trying to build jDom-b4(a Java library) from the source with the script provided in the source.

The content of script named `build.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo
echo "Java and XML Build System"
echo "-------------------"
echo

if [ "$JAVA_HOME" = "" ] ; then
  echo "ERROR: JAVA_HOME not found in your environment."
  echo
  echo "Please, set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the"
  echo "location of the Java Virtual Machine you want to use."
  exit 1
fi

LOCALCLASSPATH=$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar:./lib/xerces.jar:./lib/ant.jar:$JAVA_HOME/lib/dev.jar
ANT_HOME=./lib

echo Building with classpath $CLASSPATH:$LOCALCLASSPATH
echo

echo Starting Ant...
echo

$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -Dant.home=$ANT_HOME -classpath $LOCALCLASSPATH:$CLASSPATH org.apache.tools.ant.Main $*
```

I run it with `sh ./build.sh` and then got this error message:

```
: command not found 
: command not found echo
Java and XML Build System
-------------------
: command not found echo
: command not found 
./build.sh: line 26: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

I don't understand what the error message means. I found the message `: command not found` puzzling: what command not found? echo?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the problem is that the script was written on Windows so the newline needs to be converted. In my Vim, I used `:set ff=unix` to convert the newline to unix style and then saved the file. It worked out fine. Hope this can be helpful for other people as well.